# Wood burning stove position in room

Tags: heating, woodstove

Currently, I have a wood burning stove with a double elbow flue going into the chimney.  I'd like to get rid of the double elbow and that would mean that I move the stove approximately 4 feet to the right.  I have heard that if the wood stove is not positioned in the center of the room, the temperature differences on the right and left side of the stove will, over time, distort and break down the stove itself.  I'd really like to move the stove due to the double elbow being an insurance thing, and overall aesthetics.

Can a wood burning stove be positioned close, but not completely in the center of the room without wearing down the stove over time? What other implications other than having one side of the room being warmer than the other? Are there any other concerns about having an off-centered wood burner?

Comment: The position of the stove in the room should not alter the life of the stove. I have never heard of a stove's position in a room affecting it's useful life. If you have any problem heating the room run a small fan somewhere in the room to move the air around the room or install a ceiling fan to move the air.

Comment: I read somewhere that the temp difference will effect the rate and amount of expansion and contraction on each side of the stove. Not sure where though